# How do I push an update out to users through AppSource

Tags: office-js, office-store

If I publish an update to an existing Office add-in in AppSource, is that update pushed out to users automatically?

How do I make sure that users receive updates?

Comment: After 2 hours this is at -3. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to update an Office add-in currently published on AppSource, you will need to resubmit the add-in to validation. Once the add-in has been reviewed by the validation team, assuming no issues are found, it will be approved and the add-in update will be automatically rolled out to existing users who acquired the add-in via AppSource.

Comment: Is that true even if the manifest doesn't change? For instance, could I just update taskpane.html without re-submitting or would that break existing installations?